# Rewrite and hide page ID from URL

Tags: php, url-rewriting

I am working with the following on a football website and when a user clicks an event they get the following URL format:

- `/live/1/event-name.html`

Currently the number in the URL represents the ID number of the page, but ideally I'd like to hide this so it returns the following URL:

- `/live/event-name.html`

How can I rewrite and hide the page ID number in the URL path completely.

Comment: You can't pass something in the URL and hide it. If it's not in the URL then it's not in the URL. You will need something "unique" in the URL in order to lookup the appropriate resource. For instance, is `india-pakistan.html` unique and indexed in your database? Take the stack exchange URL structure... the ID (eg. `93745` for this page) must be present in the URL for it to "work".

Comment: Yep, you could rewrite it as a long as the `event-name.html` never appears more than once. As pretty as it may look without the ID number, most times it best to leave them alone.

Comment: @w3dk  thats a very good solution but there is an issue with this logic i went over with this logic already,event name cannot be unique like i can have two same matches india vs pakistan mutiple times in a a week if i use events name then there will duplication and i cannot differenciate

Comment: Simon that's the issue it can appear more than once.

Comment: In that case, if there is nothing else unique in the URL, then what you are proposing is not possible.

Answer (score 3):

In your case, use actual event names instead of ID numbers as unique values both in the URL and any database you are running in the back-end of your website.

Your rewrite rule probably (assuming your server is apache) has a line like this:

```
RewriteRule ^live/([0-9]+)/(.*)\.html$ processevent.php?ID=$1&Name=$2 [L]
```

Change that line to:

```
RewriteRule ^live/(.*)\.html$ processevent.php?Name=$1 [L]
```

Then again, you'll want to replace `.*` with a stricter regex expression to ensure appropriate characters are in the URL. Maybe something like this will work better for you:

```
RewriteRule ^live/([A-Za-z0-9\-]+)\.html$ processevent.php?Name=$1 [L]
```

In your back-end script, access whatever database your script uses and use the event name to seek relevant data required to process the page. You may want to consider making the event name the primary key of the database table.

Comment: That's a very good solution but there is an issue with this logic I went over with this logic already,event name cannot be unique like I can have two same matches India vs Pakistan multiple times in a a week if i use events name then there will duplication and I cannot differentiate the purpose of using id was to ensure uniqueness.have a look at this URL I want my URL to be something like this.    `http://example.com/watch/live/hawthorn-hawks-vs-brisbane-lions-live-streaming`

Comment: Maybe include the event date in the URL as well as the name, and if that still isn't unique enough, then include the estimated time of the event as well.